# "Google search" plug-in for Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, plugins, google-search

I wonder if there is a Notepad++ plugin that adds a "Google search" line into NP++ context menu (mouse right-click), so that I could highlight some text, then right-click on it, select "Search in Google" and a web-browser opened with the search page?

Comment: I really doubt so, but it would [take only 10 minutes](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/contribute/plugin-howto.html) to make your own plugin (if you have Visual Studio). Alternatively you can use something like [Launchy](http://www.launchy.net/) together with [weby](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchy#Included_Plugins) (I think that's built-in already, not sure).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to achieve what you want is...
Use Notepad++ plugin- NPPExec ([Link to the plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/forums/forum/672146)). You can also get it through Notepad++ ["Plugin manager" plugin](http://www.welancers.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/npp-plugins.png) .

Install it and press F6 or select from the menu. [See NPPExec in Menu](http://monkeywire.files.wordpress.com/2009/11/10312009_24620am5b55d.jpg).Write the following command in the box that appears. Then you may save it.

```
"C:\Users\YOURNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" http://www.google.com/search?q=$(CURRENT_WORD)
```

The selected word will be mapped to CURRENT_WORD. I have shown with Chrome. You may use other web browser as well.

REFERENCE: [You may look at this](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=External_Programs#Document_level_environment_variables) and [this](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Compiling_Source_Code)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works. Moreover, while playing with the Plugin manager I accidentally found out that the "Google search" is a NP++ built-in feature. You just need to press Alt+F2 for Google search and Alt+F3 for Wikipedia search.

Answer (score 8):

I'm a little late to the party but this feature is already available and has been for a while now. I'm currently using NP++ 6.4.5. Go to Settings -> Edit Context PopupMenu. 
Click ok to the following prompt:

```
Editing contextMenu.xml allows you to modify your Notepad++ popup context menu.
You have to restart your Notepad++ to take effect after modifying contextMenu.xml.
```

Add the following line to that file where you want the option to show up in the context menu.

```
<Item MenuEntryName="Run" MenuItemName="Google Search"/>
```

Save, restart NP++, sit back and enjoy searching Google from NP++

Answer (score 2):

This is already implemented in NP++. When you highlight a text and right click, there is an entry named `Search on Internet` in the context menu.

[image: Search on Internet, in the right-click context menu]

To change the default search engine (it is Google by default), check your `Settings` -> `Preferences` -> `Search Engine` to choose Google, DuckDuckGo, etc. You can even add Bing or others (see [Here’s how to add Bing Search to Notepad++ again](https://techdows.com/2021/06/heres-how-to-add-bing-search-to-notepad.html)).